# Selenium C# MSTest - Failed to configure settings for runsettings plugin 'VSTest Run Configuration'

Tags: firefox, c#-4.0, selenium, mstest

While executing selenium automation test in Visual Studio 12 Unit Test Project is giving following error:

```
------ Discover test started ------
Failed to configure settings for runsettings plugin 'VSTest Run Configuration' as it threw following exception:
'An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 14.'
Please contact the plugin author.
Failed to configure settings for runsettings plugin 'VSTest Run Configuration' as it threw following exception:
'An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 14.'
Please contact the plugin author.
--------------------------
```

Test Method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Login()
{
      IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.co.in");
}
```

Environment: OS: Win7 64bit / FireFox 32.0 / Seleniom client for c#(2.42.0)

## Details Error:

```
Test Name:  Test_Login
Test FullName:  SeleniumCSharp.Login.Test_Login
Test Source:    d:\Project\R&D\Selenium\SeleniumCSharp\SeleniumCSharp\Login.cs : line 31
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:48.1050863

Result Message: 
Test method SeleniumCSharp.Login.Test_Login threw exception: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to start up socket within 45000 ms. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverServer.ConnectToBrowser(TimeSpan timeToWait) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriverServer.cs:line 275
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverServer.Start() in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriverServer.cs:line 97
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.cs:line 58
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 852
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 830
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 89
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile) in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver.cs:line 151
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor() in c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Firefox\FirefoxDriver.cs:line 119
   at SeleniumCSharp.Login.Test_Login() in d:\Project\R&D\Selenium\SeleniumCSharp\SeleniumCSharp\Login.cs:line 32
```

NOTE: When i executed the test method for the first time it got executed successfully. But for 
all subsequent execution is raising above error.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that one of the parent folders had an ampersand (&) in its title and this was causing the error... what an unhelpful error message though?  I guess an XML parser must be doing something with the directory path and that is causing the parsing error